# UIView Gradient using CAGradientLayer always blue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cagradientlayer

I am trying to create a `UIView` with a dark gray gradient:

```
UIView *sectionSpacer = [[UIView alloc] init];
sectionSpacer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = sectionSpacer.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[RGB(80, 83, 88) CGColor], (id)[RGB(69, 71, 73) CGColor], nil];
[sectionSpacer.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

[image]

For some reason the gradient view is always blue even thought the RGB values are dark grays. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just `init` the view without a frame, it'll default to `CGRectZero`, so your layer will also have `0` width and height, which is why you don't see it (the gradient you do see looks like a standard `UITableView` header that may come from elsewhere, I doubt that it is even the same view you're initializing in the code you've shown).